# How can I access the database native java.sql.Connection?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, websphere

I'm using WASCE as application server and defined a data source to PosgreSQL. I get the DB Connection from JNDI.

The problem is I want to access specific method in the PostgreSQL java.sql.Connection but WASCE wrapped this connection with their own Connection.

Specifically, I want to do something like this:

```
((org.postgresql.Connection)conn).addDataType("geometry","org.postgis.PGgeometry");
((org.postgresql.Connection)conn).addDataType("box3d","org.postgis.PGbox3d");
```

Is that possible? If yes, please share how.

EDIT:

I expect to have something like access to the original Connection from this wrapped Connection, but I can't find any until now.

Comment: obviously the method is not found, while this method is not in  java.sql.Connection but only in org.postgresql.Connection.

Comment: nanda: Do you not mean, obviously a `ClassCastException` is thrown?

Comment: ah yes... sorry... I'm not in front of the development machine right now.

Answer (score 3):

Generally connections will be handled through a pool. In order to be handled (relatively) transparently you will get a proxy to the real connection. Therefore, you cannot successfully cast the connection directly. The connection pool may have an API that allows you to get to the underlying connection.

Comment: Yes... I expect to have something like that, but I can't find any until now.

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
((PooledConnection) conn).getConnection()
```

Or, since Java 1.6:

```
conn.unwrap(...)
```